# Multiple form in admin form Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, knockoutjs, adminform

I'm using magento 2.3.4, I have a database structure like this:

```
 //event
|event_id | name  |
+---------+-------+
|    1    |  Art  |
|    2    | Expo3 |

// score
| event_id |   judge     |   score  |            comment         | 
+----------+-------------+----------+----------------------------+
|     1    |   Joe       |    5     | hmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm |
|     1    |   Love      |    4     | gooooooooooooooooooooooodd |
|     1    |   Beck      |  4.5     | wooooooooooooooahhhhhhhhhh |
|     2    |   Candence  |    3     | ouchhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh |
```

The score table is related to the event table

I want to make a form in admin Magento 2, this form will have to add/edit the event table and add/edit multiple score for the event, I need to have like multiple score form that I can add/edit like this:

[image]

how can I achieve something like this for Magento 2 admin form?

Comment: Check with this link https://bsscommerce.com/confluence/ui-components-how-to-use-dynamicrows-components-in-magento-2/ and module in github module https://github.com/bbakalov/Bss_DynamicRows/tree/master/app/code/Bss/DynamicRows/Model

Answer (score 0):

you can take reference from a customer_index_edit.xml from module-customer from vendor/magento folder if you want to render through the ui component